# How to dismiss the Popoverviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I have select the `Popoverviewcontroller` segue in `storyboard` for IPad over `UIBarbutton` to view controller.
When i select one time on the add button it displays the `Popoverviewcontroller`, I want to dismiss the `popover` when the `Popoverviewcontroller` screen is present and user click the add button again.

It is working if user tab outside the `Popoverviewcontroller` but it not working with the `UIButton` which is connected with segue to popover view controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `prepareForSegue` method you need to assign your `popoverController` and set its `delegate` so you can access it. Then you can access that `popoverController` from your `viewController` and dismiss the popover with your action method.

Create a `popoverController` property and assign it from your `prepareForSegue`

```
_poController = ((UIStoryboardPopoverSegue*)segue).popoverController;
_poController.delegate = self;
```

In your action method.

```
[_poController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Extracted to a universal app-compatible category [available here](https://gist.github.com/30b50baa954ec395227b)